# What kinds of 'link-time constant' and 'assembly-time constant' are?

Tags: assembly

When I read an assembly programming book I came across the term 'assembly-time constants'. I searched it on the internet, and they said:

> the offset of 'assembly-time constant' can be computed by the
>   assembler but, the offset of 'link-time constant' can be known only at
>   link time.

I wonder what are link-time constants and assembly-time constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembly-time constants are constants present on your own 'module' so the assembler can calculate anything related with them (mainly the offset).

Link-time constants are constants present on other modules that will be linked when you build the application. At link time these constants will be resolved by the linker, not by the compiler.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!! it really helped me